# Wifi slows down heavily when bluetooth is used

Tags: networking, bluetooth

I am currently experiencing this issue with a Dell Inspiron 5000 laptop, when using internet through wifi, when I use Bluetooth the speed of the internet drops almost to a stop, from getting 20 mbps it goes down to 512kbps if I am lucky, using "options iwlwifi bt_coex_active=0" does not improve the connection in anyway,is there anyway to solve this issue, unfortunately the laptop does not support 5Ghz to try a different frequency

Comment: Bluetooth uses 2.4Ghz, so if your wifi is also on the 2.4Ghz bandwidth, the two will interfere with each other.

Comment: I expect some interference, however there is no reason for it to come to a complete halt, smartphones and tablets are able to work using wifi and bluetooth at the same time, even consoles use Bluetooth on controllers and wifi connecting to the router, so there is no real reason for this to be this bad.

Comment: You are trying to compare apples & oranges.  Phones/tablets usually get different traffic to a pc browser due to different user-id string being sent and the site sending much less info due to smaller screen etc  (even if bluetooth traffic use is ~ the same). Consoles likewise usually send small data packets which may be different to the data you are wanting on your laptop. Explore your wireless traffic if you need to know using another device 'sniffing' the wireless data it sees, or explore packet size/freq from devices going thru your access point.

Comment: Another thought - explore the strength of signal from your dell laptop, and contrast with other devices.  It could be your AP (access point) is listening to the louder/clearer device & the laptop is thus ignored due to poor antenna or location & thus signal strength.

Comment: Shoudn't `options iwlwifi bt_coex_active=0` be set to 1?